# Shell command not executing in Java

Tags: java, command-line, sybase

Normally when i do this:

```
printf 'select x from Y \ngo\n' | isql -Uxx -Pxxxxxx -Dxxxxx -w 65535 -s ','
```

on the command line it executes fine.

even with the below java code. it works fine

```
public class test
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
   String DB="|isql -Uxx -Pxxxxxx -Dxxxxx -w 65535 -s ','";
   String qpfx="printf \'";
   String qsfx=" \ngo\n\'";
   if(args[0]!=null)
        try {
            String cmd=qpfx+args[0]+qsfx+DB;
            System.out.println("argument query is:"+args[0]);
            System.out.println("Command is:"+cmd);

            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"sh","-c",cmd});

            p.waitFor();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line=reader.readLine();

            while (line != null) {    
                System.out.println(line);
                line = reader.readLine();
            }

        }
        catch(IOException e1) {}
        catch(InterruptedException e2) {}

 }
}
```

I will run this above java code like below:

```
java test "select x from Y"
```

Probelm comes when i give the select query as "select * from Y" instead of column names.
That is when i wanted to execute like below:

```
java test "select * from Y"
```

The above jav code hangs.Can any body tell me the reason why?

below is the output where its hanging:

```
> java test "select * from Y"
argument query is:select * from Y
Command is:printf 'select * from Y
go
'|isql -Uxx -Pxxxxx -Dxxxxxx -w 65535 -s ','
```

I also tried:

```
java test "select \* from Y"
```

But it does not execute.

Comment: I dont use shell commands with Java so I may be wrong but could you try removing \ before `'` in your Strings? Or are there necessary?

Comment: Does using `String qsfx=" ;go;\'";` make a difference?

Comment: What does the line: `System.out.println("Command is:"+cmd);` print in output?

Comment: No neither removing \before ' nor putting ; worked.

Comment: So what happens when you execute `printf 'select * from Y \ngo\n' | isql -Uxx -Pxxxxxx -Dxxxxx -w 65535 -s ','` from the command line?

Comment: As i said, it ran on command line without any problem:
`printf 'select * from Y\ngo\n'|isql -Uxx -Pxxxxxxx -Dxxxxx -w 65535 -s ','`. Problem comes only when i have a * over here. Instead of * if i have any column name of that table . It works fine even from inside java.

Comment: Try to escape the `\n` characters. E.g. use `String qsfx=" \\ngo\\n\'";` (btw: you don't need to escape single quotes)

Comment: @c.s Even if i escape \n with \ it is hanging:`
argument query is:select * from BSC
Command is:printf 'select * from BSC\ngo\n'|isql -Usa -Psybase11 -Dbsmdb -w 65535 -s ','`

Comment: Try to pass `new String[]{"sh","-c", "\"" + cmd + "\""}`  (note the last quotes around `cmd`)

Comment: @c.s Nope it does not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After severe debugging i found that the line that is hanging is `p.waitFor();`.

I had to read [this](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html) complete article and then i finally found a solution.
I have shifted the  `p.waitFor();` after the while loop in the code and it worked.